# D3 - forEach is not a function when upgrading from v3 to v4

Tags: javascript, d3.js, foreach

I am trying to upgrade [this](http://bl.ocks.org/KatiRG/f7d064cd9c3efbc3c360) stackable bar chart to v4.
Everything works except for one thing.

When I filter one category the bars don't drop to the start of the x-axis. I get an error which says:

> state.selectAll(...).forEach is not a function

I've tried multiple things but I can't figure this one out.
This is the broken code:

```
function plotSingle(d) {

class_keep = d.id.split("id").pop();
idx = legendClassArray.indexOf(class_keep);

//erase all but selected bars by setting opacity to 0
d3.selectAll(".bars:not(.class" + class_keep + ")")
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .attr("width", 0) // use because svg has no zindex to hide bars so can't select visible bar underneath
    .style("opacity", 0);

//lower the bars to start on x-axis
state.selectAll("rect").forEach(function(d, i) {

    //get height and y posn of base bar and selected bar
    h_keep = d3.select(d[idx]).attr("height");
    y_keep = d3.select(d[idx]).attr("y");

    h_base = d3.select(d[0]).attr("height");
    y_base = d3.select(d[0]).attr("y");

    h_shift = h_keep - h_base;
    y_new = y_base - h_shift;

    //reposition selected bars
    d3.select(d[idx])
        .transition()
        .ease("bounce")
        .duration(1000)
        .delay(750)
        .attr("y", y_new);

})
}
```

I find it strange that this works flawlessly in D3 v3, why wouldn't this work in v4?

Comment: should `state.selectAll` instead be `d3.selectAll`?

Answer (score 6):

In d3 v3 selectAll returned an array, in d3 v4 it returns an object.

From the [v3 notes](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Selections.md):

> Selections are arrays of elements—literally (maybe not literally...).
>   D3 binds additional methods to the array so that you can apply
>   operators to the selected elements, such as setting an attribute on
>   all the selected elements.

Where as [changes in v4](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#selections-d3-selection) include:

> Selections no longer subclass Array using prototype chain injection;
>   they are now plain objects, improving performance. The internal fields
>   (selection._groups, selection._parents) are private; please use the
>   documented public API to manipulate selections. The new
>   selection.nodes method generates an array of all nodes in a selection.

If you want to access each node in v4 try:

```
selection.nodes().forEach( function(d,i) { ... })
```

But, this is just the node, to get the data you would need to select each node:

```js
var data = [0,1,2];

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width",500)
  .attr("height",200)

var circles = svg.selectAll("circle")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cx", function(d,i) { return i * 20 + 50 })
  .attr("cy", 50)
  .attr("r", 4);
  
  
circles.nodes().forEach(function(d,i) {
    console.log(d3.select(d).data());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.10.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

But, if you need the data or to modify the selection properties, it could be easier to use selection.each(). d3.each iterates through each element of a d3 selection itself, and allows you to invoke a function for each element in a selection (see API docs [here](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_each)):

```js
var data = [0,1,2];

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width",500)
  .attr("height",200)

var circles = svg.selectAll("circle")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cx", function(d,i) { return i * 20 + 50 })
  .attr("cy", 50)
  .attr("r", 4);
  

  
circles.each( function() {
  console.log(d3.select(this).data());  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.10.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

---

In v3 of this bar chart, in the forEach loop

```
`states.selectAll("rect").forEach(function(d,i) {`
```

d  is an array of nodes (the rectangles in each `.g`).

But, in v4 d3 selections aren't arrays, you can't use a forEach loop in the same way. But you can still get the nodes in it without much modification using `selection.nodes()` and than get the childNodes to replicate the array in the v3 version:

```
state.nodes().forEach(function(d, i) {
            var nodes = d.childNodes;
```

Here we go through each element/node in `state` and get the child `rect`s, returned as an array. Here's an updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yeyhhc7t/2/).

Comment: Thanks, this seems to fix this issue. Although I immediately encountered the next problem. The y_new value can't be calculated properly. I think it has to do with the idx value because the console logs 'Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null', but I can't seem to find the correct way to fix this.

Comment: @kevintaffee Have you tried the .each, and can you provide a minimal example that can be used as a demonstration?

Comment: @AndrewReid You have a small glitch in your last paragraph. It should read `selection.each()`, there is no such thing as `d3.each()`.

Comment: @AndrewReid I have tried each instead of forEach, without any succes. I have made a Jsfiddle to demonstrate. Can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/tb2gxv92/)

Comment: @altocumulus, thanks, had it the sentence before, but messed it up afterwards.

Comment: @kevintaffee, I've updated the answer and have provided an updated fiddle. I'm going to expand a bit probably later to provide more rationale on why the approach looks a little different beyond the use of .nodes()